# How do I properly allocate an array within a struct with malloc and realloc in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, struct

I'm trying to implement a stack in C, while also trying to learn C. My background is mostly in higher languages (like Python), so a lot of the memory allocation is new to me.

I have a program that works as expected, but throws warnings that make me believe I'm doing something wrong.

Here is the code:

```
typedef struct {
    int num_items;
    int top;
    int items[];
} stack;

void push(stack *st, int n) {
    st->num_items++;

    int* tmp = realloc(st->items, (st->num_items) * sizeof(int));

    if (tmp) {
        *(st->items) = tmp;
    }

    st->items[st->num_items - 1] = n;
    st->top = n;
}

int main() {
    stack *x = malloc(sizeof(x));
    x->num_items = 0;
    x->top = 0;
    *(x->items) = malloc(0);

    push(x, 2);
    push(x, 3);

    printf("Stack top: %d, length: %d.\n", x->top, x->num_items);

    for (int i = 0; i < x->num_items; i++) {
        free(&(x->items[i]));
    }
    free(x->items);
    free(x);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Stack top: 3, length: 2.
```

Which is expected. But during compilation, I get the following errors:

```
> gcc -x c -o driver driver.c
driver.c: In function 'push':
driver.c:16:16: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
    *(st->items) = tmp;
...
driver.c: In function 'main':
driver.c:27:14: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
    *(x->items) = malloc(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your belief is correct. Usually - that is almost always - warnings from C compiler are signs of grave programming errors that will cause serious problems. Quoting [Shooting yourself in the foot in various programming languages](http://www.toodarkpark.org/computers/humor/shoot-self-in-foot.html):

> **C**
>
> - You shoot yourself in the foot.
> - You shoot yourself in the foot and then nobody else can figure out what you did.

---

The problem is that you're coding as if `items` was a *pointer* to int, yet you have declared and defined it as a *flexible array member* (FAM), which is an entirely different beast altogether. And since *assigning to an array would produce an error*, i.e.

```
x->items = malloc(0);
```

would be an error, you've come up with something that compiles with just warnings. Remember that errors are better than warnings, because they stop you from shooting yourself into foot.

---

The solution is to declare `items` as a *pointer to `int`* instead:

```
int *items;
```

and use

```
x->items = ...;
```

to get the pointer behaviour you expect.

Also,

```
free(&(x->items[i]));
```

is very wrong, since you never allocated the *`i`th* integer to begin with; they were objects in the array. Also, you don't need `malloc(0)`; just initialize with a null pointer:

```
x->items = NULL;
```

`realloc` and `free` wouldn't mind the null pointer.

---

The flexible array member means that the last element in the structure is an array of indefinite length, so in `malloc` you would reserve enough memory for it too:

```
stack *x = malloc(sizeof x + sizeof *x->items * n_items);
```

The flexible array member is used in CPython for objects like `str`, `bytes` or `tuple` that are of immutable length - it is slightly faster to use a FAM instead of a pointer elsewhere, and it saves memory - especially with shorter strings or tuples.

---

Finally, notice that your stack becomes slower the more it grows - the reason is because you're always allocating just one more element. Instead, you should scale the size of the stack by a *factor* (1.3, 1.5, 2.0?), so that insertions run in `O(1)` time as opposed to `O(n)`; and consider what will happen should `realloc` fail - perhaps you should be more loud about it!

Comment: Chose this as the accepted solution because it contains the most amount of information in one place and even offers help on improving the algorithm. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you have an empty array declared at the end of the structure like you have, it's called a [*flexible array member*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). And you allocate it not by allocating just the array member, but by allocating the *whole structure*.

Like e.g.

```
stack *x = malloc(sizeof *x + sizeof s->items[0] * 32);
```

The above `malloc` call allocates space for the structure itself (note the use of the dereference operator for `sizeof *x`) plus space for an array of 32 elements.

It's either the above, or change the member to be a pointer.

Comment: Changing the member would be the logical approach as otherwise you'd need to make the code handle `realloc` changing the memory location of the whole structure

Comment: @ChrisTurner True, but it can easily be worked around by remembering to update e.g. `x` properly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude @ChrisTurner if I used this in main and in push did something like `stack* tmp = realloc(st, sizeof(*st) + st->num_items * sizeof(st->items[0]));` and then assigned st to be tmp, would that be the preferred solution? Or would it be preferred to just change the member?

Comment: @Dylan As noted by Chris Turner it might be easier to work with a pointer member, but there's really no "correct" solution here. Both are valid, and it's just up to your own preference which one you want to use.

Comment: @Dylan You'd have to redefine `push` to take a `stack **` and assign `tmp` to `*st` - otherwise you'd lose the change once you left the function

Answer (score 2):

This is an array of unspecified size

```
int items[];
```

This is a pointer

```
int *items;
```

The latter is what you use with `malloc`/`realloc` to make use of dynamically allocated memory.

Also, because you're doing (for example)

```
*(x->items) = malloc(0);
```

...you're de-referencing items so that it becomes an `int` which is why you're getting those particular warnings.